# RS232 Serial communication in QNX Nuetrino RTOS

Tags: serial-port, serial-communication, qnx-neutrino

In present, I am using LAN cable for communication between HOST and TARGET. Now I want to use RS232 to receive simulated data from QNX Neutrino only. Through LAN I want to transfer data to QNX Neutrino.

How can I setup this?

Comment: What is QNX version you use ????

Answer (score 0):

simple sending data

```
cat filename > /dev/serN
```

and you can read data from the serial port in the same way:

```
cat /dev/serN > somefilename.txt
```

where N id number of using serial port

serial ports exist in

```
ls /dev | grep ser
```